# Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xE2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8): error in ROR + MongoDB based app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, encoding, utf-8

Had a developer write this method and its causing a Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xE2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8):  error.

This error only happens randomly so the data going in is original DB field is what is causing the issue. But since I don't have any control over that, what can I put in the below method to fix this so bad data doesn't cause any issues?

```
def scrub_string(input, line_break = ' ')
  begin
     input.an_address.delete("^\u{0000}-\u{007F}").gsub("\n", line_break)
  rescue
     input || ''
  end
end
```

Will this work?

```
 input = input.encode('utf-8', :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => '_')
```

Comment: Please post the whole backtrace of the error.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah this should work, it'll replace any weird characters that can't be converted into UTF-8 with an underscore.

Read more about encoding strings in ruby here:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-encode

Answer (score 0):

Using the `force_encoding("UTF-8")` method on the string worked for me.

#### Example

This example uses random data from a whois request (you can try for yourself).

This errors for me:

```rb
# gem install whois

whois = Whois::Client.new
mystring = whois.lookup("google.com").to_s
puts mystring

# (irb):38:in `write': "\xE2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 
# (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)
```

But this works!

```rb
whois = Whois::Client.new
mystring = whois.lookup("google.com").to_s
puts mystring.force_encoding("UTF-8")
```

The key difference is calling `force_encoding("UTF-8")` on the string before printing it.

It's from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66243555/5783745).